# TextBox MultiLine within winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, escaping

How to insert a new line in textbox whithin winforms application :

```
 textBox2.Text += "a";
 textBox2.Text += "\n";
 textBox2.Text += "b";
```

But the I get one row even I made the textbox multiline :

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Windows line break is CRLF. You'd be better off using `Environment.NewLine` anyway.

Comment: so try appending this: "\r\n" or Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine`

```
textbox.Multiline = true;
textbox.Text += "a" + Environment.NewLine + "b";
```

Answer (score 1):

for Windows OS you should write `\r\n` for new line.

for Mac OS you should use `\n` only.

The `Environment.NewLine` will work for both operating system. Thus, you can make your code common for both platform. So, avoid `\n` and `\r\n` in the string when your application code is created for both operating system.

in your case you can use `String.Format` to avoid multiple concatenation which will slow down the performance when it is being used in long process.

```
textBox2.Text = String.Format("ABCD{0}XYZ", Environment.NewLine);
```

if you are concatenating bunch of lines then there is better way to do this. You can use `StringBuilder` class for that.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string line in Lines)
{
    sb.AppendLine(line);
    //or 
    //sb.AppendFormat("My line: {0}{1}", line, Environment.NewLine);
}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

`StringBuilder.AppendLine()` can be used also to add lines when you combining more than one lines.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said you need CRLF which means:

```
textBox2.Text += "a";
textBox2.Text += "\r\n";
textBox2.Text += "b";
```

But as Amir correctly said, `Environment.NewLine` will do the trick as well and you don't have to bother with "how a newline is represented".

Comment: _you don't have to bother with "how a newline is represented"._ Or put the other way around: for the price of a lot more typing you lose control of what you actually get.